# Is there a better method for bulk entry?

Tags: mysql-8.0

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Student (  
    SID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
    Address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,     
    Telephone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
    Age INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT UC_Person UNIQUE (SID, Name)
);

CREATE TABLE Course (  
        CourseNo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
        Title VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,  
        Department VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,     
        NumberOfCredits VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
        CourseFees FLOAT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT UC_Course UNIQUE (CourseNo,Title)
);

CREATE TABLE Registration (  
    SID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  
    CourseNo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
    StartDate DATE NOT NULL,     
    CompleteDate DATE NULL,
    Grade FLOAT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (SID) REFERENCES Student(SID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CourseNo) REFERENCES Course(CourseNo)
);
```

I've populated the `Course` and `Student` tables, with 825 CourseNo and 1000 SID, respectively.

The only way I know how to enter data into a table is:

```
INSERT INTO REGISTRATION ('SID','CourseNo','StartDate','CompleteDate','Grade') VALUES

('3', 'COMP418', '2018-09-01', NULL, NULL),
('3', 'COMP470', '2018-09-01', NULL, NULL),
('3', 'COMP314', '2018-05-01', '2018-08-31', '85.67');
```

This works, HOWEVER, I have an x8 CourseNo, x2 StartDate, x2 CompleteDate, x8 Grade, to enter per SID. With 1000 SID in my database this is going to take forever using my above example. I'm sure there is a faster way but I have no idea how.

Can someone please explain how?

Comment: Do the values in each record to be inserted have anything in common?

Comment: Each SID is unique as it represents a Student ID No. Each CourseNo can be entered for many SID. The StartDate is not unique to anything, and the CompleteDate and Grade fields do not have to be entered, but I would like to enter for these two fields as I feel fit. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL offers the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command, and tools like HeidiSQL and Mysqlworkbench have features to import .csv files. What you need as a starting point is a flat file with some sort of delimiter between columns of data.

This way of loading data is almost miraculously fast compared to a mess of INSERT queries.